# Need to modify WP widget to use target=_blank

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to modify a obox slider to include the HTML for `target="_blank"`. Here's the code I'm working on but I'm too much of a beginner to PHP to get it. Should be easy for someone who knows the syntax..

```
// $string1=" target=_blank;  // I added this but don't think I need it...
$link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slider_link', true );
//if ( $link != "" )  want to check if there is a url and if so add target=blank
    //<a href="<?php echo $link  //   don't know how to do this...
    //$link=$link.$string1;  // I added this line as well

if( $link == "" )
    $link = get_permalink($post->ID); ?>        
    <li>
        <?php if($image !="") : ?>
         <div class="fitvid">
             <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                 <?php echo $image; ?>
             </a>
         </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You just want to add `target="_blank"` to the link that is under the DIV with `class="fitvid"`?

Comment: yes, that should do it I think.   What is the exact code then?

Comment: do not understand. `<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">`

Comment: Hmmm..   lolka_bolka tried that but it didn't work.   Target was still ending up being _self...   Is there a way to build the html code in it's entirety and store it in the $link variable??

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `target="_blank"` in the link.

```
            $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slider_link', true );
            $postLink = get_permalink($post->ID); ?>        
            <li>
                <?php if($image !="") : ?>
                    <div class="fitvid">
                        <a href="<?php echo ($link != '') ? $link . '" target="_blank"' : $postLink . '"'; ?>>
                            <?php echo $image; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes that did work.   Is there a way to put in a if statement to check for $link !="" ????

Comment: You only want the link on the image if there is a link? Otherwise, just show the image?

Comment: Well no, if there is a link it needs to be on the image.   My question is how to keep the default functionality which is to use the link to the post on the WP site and keep the default of target=self when there is no link in the custom slider link field.   When link has something in it and is not blank, it should add the target=_blank.

Comment: $postLink = get_permalink($post->ID); ?>   It complains about this line that "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class feature_posts_widget in  on line 211"